# Hide all files with a specific extension from Finder

Tags: finder

I have an application that creates MANY .log, .upload, and .json files each day, so that when I go to my "Today" smart folder, it's all clogged up with those. I'd like to hide all three of those file extensions from finder, but I'm not sure the best way to do so given that I'd need the solution to work on new files with those extensions as well as existing ones.

Alternately, I could hide all existing and new files in a particular folder since that folder houses all of those, but I want them also to be invisible to my smart folders.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I'm confortable USING scripts and automator and such, but I don't know the commands myself, so the more specific you can be in your answers, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to hide them from the "Today" Smart Folder or to hide them altogether? Keep in mind that hiding them altogether will probably make it impossible to locate the files with Spotlight & Finder, and may require you to use Terminal to access them. Your clarification will help provide a better answer.

Comment: I don't need to be able to locate the files, so using Terminal to find them would be fine. 

Hiding them only from the smart folder would be OK if that's the best solution, but I'd prefer to hide them completely.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to modify the saved search, copy it somewhere from `/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/CannedSearches/Today.cannedSearch`, show package contents and open `search.savedSearch` in a text editor, and add this to the first RawQuery key:

`&amp;&amp; kMDItemFSName != *.log &amp;&amp; kMDItemFSName != *.upload &amp;&amp; kMDItemFSName != *.json`

You can drop it on the sidebar by holding command.

Comment: Thanks. This worked!

I also realized I could just create a new smart folder with files that had only been OPENED today, not modified, created, etc. So simple!

I'd still love to just hide those irritating files, but this will do for now.